# Call javascript from code behind c# sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have this code in my .ascx.cs file which calls to new page on href.

```
lblVideoAssessment.Text = "<a href='../SitePages/Assessment.aspx?cat=" + cat + "' height='300px' width='300px' Target='_blank' cssClass='IconDisplayCss'><img src='~/_layouts/images/Assessment.png' border='none'/></a><br/>" + cat;
```

I want to replace this code to javascript popup page to change look and feel.i want to make page as popup for which i have written a javascript method in .ascx file which is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDialog(URL) {
        var NewPopUp = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        NewPopUp.url = URL;
        NewPopUp.width = 700;
        NewPopUp.height = 350;
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(NewPopUp);
    }
 </script>
```

I have called the javascript in code behind like this and it does not work:

```
lblVideoAssessment.Text = "<a OnClick='javascript:OpenDialog('../SitePages/Quiz.aspx')' height='300px' width='300px' Target='_blank' cssClass='IconDisplayCss'><img src='~/_layouts/images/Assessment.png' border='none'/></a><br/>" + cat;
```

Please advice what to do.
    The same works fine with sharepoint designer.
    Please help how to pass the javascript method on OnClick.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you simply want the html that you are assigning to `lblVideoAssessment.Text` to be placed in the page, exactly as it is. For that, an `<asp:Label ... />` is not the right type of control to use.

Instead, you want an [`<asp:Literal ... />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx). Then the assignment will be basically the same as what you currently have:

```
litVideoAssessment.Text = "<a OnClick='javascript:OpenDialog('../SitePages/Quiz.aspx')' height='300px' width='300px' Target='_blank' cssClass='IconDisplayCss'><img src='~/_layouts/images/Assessment.png' border='none'/></a><br/>" + cat;
```